# Is there a word that means unstoppably powerful, but also fast?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means something that is powerful, unstoppable, but also fast. "Juggernaut" covers the first part, but it implies enormous size and sluggish inertia. I feel like there's a word that fits the idea, but I can't come up with it.

It's intended to be the name of vessel, so it doesn't have to be any particular part of speech.

Comment: Sonic the Hedgehog?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [requests for names are off-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Avalanche?
Tsunami?
Landslide?
It feels like terms regarding forces of nature might fit your bill, but there may be other terms that are more human in nature if that is your goal.

Comment: Following up on that, you might look into explosions as well: blast, pressure wave, explosive etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoroid) has been used in this context. They are not unstoppable, but [they’re pretty close to it](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_event).

You could also try starting with the names of any of the larger [Felidae](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felidae).

However... you are not exactly the first person to face this problem, so a lot will depend on how original you want to be.

Comment: You mean like a puma?  ("Dangit, Grif, I told you to stop making up animals!")

Comment: I googled “puma yacht” and found this: https://www.yachtcharterfleet.com/luxury-charter-yacht-38726/puma.htm

Answer (score 0):

In terms of powerful and unyielding, ***Dauntless*** has launched many a vessel.

> incapable of being intimidated or subdued

[-Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dauntless)

synonyms include:  bold, brave, courageous, doughty, fearless, gallant, greathearted, gutsy, gutty, heroic (also heroical), intrepid, lionhearted, manful, stalwart, stout, stouthearted, undauntable, undaunted, valiant, valorous

Comment: Hi Jimalaya, welcome to EL&U. I don't think dauntless and powerful are synonyms, but in any case your answer is too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *dauntless* (linked to the source) and examples of its use. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wolverine? Badger? Honey Badger? oooo I know - fast, irascible, unpredictable, darn dangerous, large AND fast both in water AND on land - Hippopotamus!